# VisualSVN Server Manager Active Directory problem

Tags: active-directory, visualsvn-server

Cogratulations for this excellent website.

I have one question and I hope someone may help.

I had installed on Windows 2008 VisualSVN v2.03 and I was able to add users from my Active directory and give permissions to different directories.

I have updated to v 2.1.3 and I am not able to give accesss rights or browse the active directory.

I  must say that on the same server I have Sharepoint services installed and I am able to navigate to active directory using the build in add users interface.

Any suggestions

Many thanks
Lefteris

Answer (score 1):

In VisualSVN Server we made several fixes in Active Directory browsing interface. Quote from VisualSVN Server 2.1.3 [changelog entry](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v2.1.3):

> - Allow to grant access rights for a domain computer account.
> - Prohibit to grant access rights for a domain distribution group (since
>     Active Directory distribution groups
>     are not intended to manage
>     permissions).

So I recommend you to report your problem to VisualSVN Support Team. They will be happy to investigate and fix your issue.